# Is redux Toolkit only used for Hooks ? If not please provide official documentation for using RTK for Class Components & video content online

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Is redux Toolkit only used for Hooks ? If not please provide official documentation and video content online!

if possible please provide any youtube videos link which explains Redux Toolkit in Class components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React class components are pretty much legacy at this point - you should really not be writing new code with them, as most new libraries do not provide functionality for it. The whole ecosystem is shifting towards a hooks-only approach since 2019.

But apart from that, React Toolkit is completely platform independent (apart from the RTK-Query `/react` entrypoint, which only provides hooks - see reasoning above).

You use Redux Toolkit with React - just like plain Redux - using the `react-redux` library, which provides the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks as well as the `connect` function, which can be used to use Redux (with or without Toolkit) with class components.

`connect` is at this point considered a legacy api. It will stay around for the forseeable future, but might work less well in some edge cases of future React 18, since React 18 is really tailored around concepts that do not work well with class components.

If you need information on that, please see the [React-Redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/), not the Redux Toolkit documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much @phry, This was really helpful. Previously I was in a impression that Class components is the best BUT BUT now after watching few videos and after facing a real pain in using class components, I found that Hooks with Redux Toolkit is the best thing and that may make life easier! Thanks for clearing my doubt and shown me right path!

Comment: Yeah, class components have essentially been abandoned by most of the community shortly after hooks were released and most modern libraries do not support them any more. It is a shame that it is so hard to find the right up-to-date information in this modern frontend jungle